# From a circle to an ellipse

Tags: matrices, circles, conic-sections

Suppose we have this matrix, \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -1   \\
    -1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}

how can we show that under the above matrix transformation, the unit circle is sent to an ellipse? I think it's with the singular decomposition...

Comment: It's about diagonalization of symmetric matrix. After a rotation it is just a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an answer with SVD, it goes like this:
The SVD shows any matrix is decomposed into orthogonal-diagonal-orthogonal. Then any matrix having the diagonal component non-zero sends the unit circle to an ellipse, because all it can do is rotate/reflect each point of the circle or stretch it along arbitrary orthogonal axes. Unless the stretch is squashing the circle along some direction, ie, if you have one or more zeros in the diagonal.